# Error running Tensorflow test model with Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to setup Tensorflow, and using Anaconda. I installed Tensorflow within the Anaconda environment, but cannot locate the Tensorflow packages in my Python library.

I have been following the setup instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup#test_the_tensorflow_installation), and had no issues running `print(sess.run(hello))`. However, in the next step, it asks to locate the MNIST package(s). When I run the command below, I get what I assume is the path to the tensorflow packages:

```
(tensorflow) adamg:TensorFlow adamg$ python -c 'import os; import inspect; import tensorflow; print(os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(tensorflow)))'
/Users/adamg/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow
```

Using that path, I then tried to run both:

```
python -m tensorflow.models.image.mnist.convolutional
```

and

```
python /Users/adamg/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py
```

but received the error:

```
python: can't open file '/Users/adamg/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I locate the correct directory?